# Sending pointer value through a message queue in POSIX in same thread: Pointer has different value on receiver side

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, posix, message-queue

I'm pretty new to threads and also not a very experienced c programmer.
I know that POSIX message queues **are used for Inter process communication**. I want to get an example code running where I use mq_send() and mq_receive() to communicate **between threads**.
I just want to pass the pointer value as the message content so the receiver thread knows where the data is stored in the shared memory
I'm doing something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mqueue.h>

typedef struct{
    uint8 elem1;
    uint8 elem2;
    uint8 elem3;
}myStruct;


myStruct myelements;

mqd_t mqd;
mqd.mq_maxmsg = 10;
mqd.mq_maxmsg = sizeof(uint32_t);  /*Want to send the pointer value through the message queue*/

void *threadMaster(void *arg)
{
    mqd.mq_maxmsg = 10;
    mqd.mq_maxmsg = sizeof(uint32_t);
    mq = mq_open("/my_queue", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666, NULL);
    if (mq == (mqd_t)-1) 
    {
        perror("mq_open");
        exit(1);
        
        while(1)
        {
            myelements.elem1 = 1;
            myelements.elem2 = 2;
            myelements.elem3 = 3;
            
            
            /*Send the pointer value through the message queue*/
            uint32_t ptr_value = (uint32_t)&myelements;
            rv = mq_send(mqd, ( const CHAR *)ptr_value, sizeof(uint32_t),0);
            
            printf("Pointer value on sender side %p",&ptr_value);  // prints  d02ae000
            
            if(rv == ERROR)
            {
                /*Handling error..*/
            }
        }
    }
}

void *threadSlave(void *arg) 
{
    // Open the message queue for reading
    mq = mq_open("/my_queue", O_RDONLY);
    if (mq == (mqd_t)-1) 
    {
        perror("mq_open");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) 
    {
        
        uint32_t recv_ptr;
        
        // Receive the pointer from the message queue
        if (mq_receive(mqd, (char *)&recv_ptr, sizeof(uint32_t), NULL) == -1) 
        {
            perror("mq_receive");
            exit(1);
        }
        
        printf("Pointer value on receiver side %p",&recv_ptr ); // prints 1002e9c4

        myStruct *recv_ptr = (myStruct *)recv_ptr;
        // Access the data using the received pointer
        printf("Received Data: elem1=%d, %elem2=%d, %elem3 =%d\n", recv_ptr.a, recv_ptr.b,
               recv_ptr.c, );
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here? I get a different pointer value on the receiver side so when accessing the data in the shared memory it will access some randome values.

Comment: `uint32_t ptr_value = (uint32_t)&myStruct;` - did you verify that `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(uint32_t)`? Because on my system it isn't

Comment: The above point would be moot if you'd use the intended `uintptr_t` which is guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer value

Comment: @UnholySheep I tried it as well with uintptr_t but still the same.

Comment: You get different value such as what? Data please.

Comment: This is *one* statement:  `typedef struct{
    uint8 elem1;
    uint8 elem2;
    uint8 elem3;
}myStruct


myStruct myelements;`  Ouch.

Comment: Also, the code can not be compiled.  There are brace mismatches after `if (mq == (mqd_t)-1) {`, and `while()` is flat-out wrong.

Comment: @user207421 I meant the pointer value. I have added comments to the code now.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I had a typo, just updated.

Comment: Why are you converting the pointer to an integer at all? Just pass `(const char*)&myStruct`

Comment: @Barmar This will work in my example here as long sizeof(myStruct) < MQ_MSGSIZE 500 bytes. But what if I deal with bigger amount of data where sizeof(myStruct) > 500 ? In that case I would need to pass only the pointer to the data. I'm trying to figure out how to to this (with my little experience) and that's why I thought it can be done as I tried it to demonstrate in my post.

Comment: I'm not suggesting passing the struct, just pass the pointer itself without converting it to integer.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I tried with mq_send(mqd, ( const CHAR *)&myelements, sizeof(myStruct ),0) . So the mq_receive() will return the number of bytes received. In this example this would be the sizeof(myStruct ). So this is going good as long as the number of received bytes is smaller than MQ_MSGSIZE 500 (defined in POSIX header). If I send more than this number of bytes the system will crash.

Comment: That's not what I'm suggesting. `myStruct *ptr_value = &myelements; mq_send(mqd, (const CHAR *)&ptr_value, sizeof(ptr_value), 0);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256368/discussion-between-johndoe-and-barmar).